# Ubuntu/Gnome Calendar bidirectional sync with google calendar

Tags: gnome, thunderbird, sync, evolution, calendar

Heyho folks,

so I am struggling with this problem for a while now and I cannot find a clear answer to be honest. 
I am using the California Calendar and have my GOA for Google set up as well. The calendar finds the set up GOA without any problems and also syncs it with the calendar app integrated in Gnome Shell (appearing in the top panel). 
I can also add events that will show up in my Google Calendar online without any problems. But when I add a new event online into the Google Calendar and the GOA already set up it won't sync onto my Laptop, so the California Calendar does not get a update on my Calendar events. 
I also tried to set it up with Thunderbird and Evolution resulting with the dead end.

Is bidirectional sync not possible, am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?

I hope I got my point clear and to maybe find someone to help me.

Cheers,
Michi

Comment: Use Syncevolution. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SyncEvolution/synchronize-multiple-google-calendars-with-evolution-calendars